# How use SSL with Play 2 Framework?

Tags: ssl, playframework, playframework-2.0, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have created a new certificate using `Let's Encrypt`, also, I was able to generate my keystore. Now I'm loading my `Play` application like this:

```
activator run -Dspring.profiles.active="dev" -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.port=9443 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/webapp/play/conf/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="password"
```

However, `Play` seems not to read my `keystore` and keeps generating a new one.

```
[warn] play - Using generated key with self signed certificate for HTTPS. This should not be used in production.
```

How can I make `Play` to read my keystore ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of Play you're on, so I'll assume you have Play 2.4.6.

Configuring SSL is documented in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ConfiguringHttps

The warning you're seeing comes from the DefaultSSLEngineProvider -- the source code is in:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/ssl/DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala#L57

So you can see looking at the documentation, you need to set `play.server.https.keyStore.path` and so on to configure SSL.

Comment: Will, how can I check my `play` version ? I run my application with `activator` only.

Comment: Look in your project/plugins.sbt file and see the addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % playVersion) // where version is the current Play version, i.e. "2.4.x" https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Build#Play-plugin-for-sbt-(/project/plugins.sbt)

Comment: Thanks Will! This is my version `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.9")`.

Comment: That means you are running Play 2.3.9.

Comment: Yes. Also means that I was doing the correct way .. but still not working.. :(

Comment: When you say "doing the correct way", you mean you looked at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ConfiguringHttps#SSL-Certificates-from-a-keystore and followed the instructions there?